# How to fix the error: null is not an object (evaluation of 'bleManager.start')?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) library to connect an Android smartphone to a BLE device. But when calling the `BleManager.start ()`, an error immediately occurred, I already looked at Issues on GitHub, the solutions that are there did not help me in solving this problem.
My steps in installing lib:

1. `npm i --save react-native-ble-manager`
2. ```js
   // file: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   ...
   ```

   I've tried using `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, both together and separately.
3. `npm i`
4. In README.md it is written that there is support autolink, but it will not be superfluous: `react-native link && react-native link react-native-ble-manager`

I don't use Expo. When running the example from the library, the same error occurs.
I use only this in my project (not example):

```js
...
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
...
const scanAndConnect = () => {
  BleManager.start()    
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

`build.gradle` info:

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

OS: Android 9.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `targetSdkVersion` for Android 9.0 was incorrectly specified, `targetSdkVersion` should be equal to 28 in file `build.gradle`